# How to count only the record in left join?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I need to count how many goals has scored a specific player into a particular team which play in a specific competition.
I have three tables:

1. Match: contains all the matches played by a team for a specific competition (round)
2. Player contains the details of a player eg: name, surname, height etc...
3. Goal: contains all the goal scored by that player in a match

This is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT
COUNT(*) AS goal_scored,
p.first_name AS first_name,
p.last_name AS last_name
FROM `match` m
LEFT JOIN goal g ON g.match_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN player p ON g.player_marker_id = p.id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
AND (m.home_team_id = :team_id OR m.away_team_id = :team_id)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY goal_scored DESC
LIMIT 5";
```

in the first part of the query I tried to select all the goal scored by the player of the searched team using a join on `goal` and `player`.
I filter those results for `round` which correspond to the competition.id.

I'm expecting to return the top scorer of the team in a specific competition.

**Data example**

Match:

```
id | home_team_id | away_team_id | 
 1        95            121
 2       203            95
 3       95             122
```

Goal:

```
id | player_marker_id | match_id | team_id | result  | type
 1         1005            1           95      1 - 0   1
 2         1005            1           95      1 - 0   2
 3         1005            2           95      2 - 1   1
 4         1006            3           95      1 - 0   1
```

Player:

```
id    | first_name | surname 
1005    Benedetto    Ismael
1006    Ramon        Abila
```

so as you can see in table `match` I have three records, this means that the team `95` have played 3 matches.
In this team there is two player, the player `Benedetto` has scored 2 goals, so is the topscorer of that team, the expected result should be:

```
Benedetto
Ramon
```

but I get as `goal_scored` an incorrect result like `3` goal scored, this is wrong because the `type` it's not important on this scope. The `type` simply tell me which type of goal is, in particular 1 is the goal that opened a match, and 2 is a normal goal. A goal can have multiple type, for a max of 2.

Also, I discovered another bug, different players can score in the same match, but the result of `goal_scored` is incorrect because I need to count only the goal scored by the specific player joined not for all players of the team.

How can I fix my query?

**Production result**

```
SELECT * FROM `match` m 
LEFT JOIN goal g ON m.id = g.match_id AND g.player_marker_id = 68165 
WHERE m.round_id = 488 AND (m.home_team_id = 95 OR m.away_team_id = 95)
```

[image]

Comment: What does type 2 mean? I'm looking at goals and I can see that the player 1005 has 3 goals. You may need to group by match_id as well. Also do COUNT(DISTINCT g.id)

Comment: @Monofuse type = 1 is a goal that opened a match, type = 2 is a simple goal, I have also type = 3 that's a penalty, type = 4 wrong penalty

Comment: Then the only thing I can see is that you need to group on g.match_id. The only time Benedetto scored 2 goals is if you only take the match with id 1 into account.

Comment: @Monofuse check my update please

Comment: I know this has been resolved, but I'd recommend enum flags to you. Instead of having to insert the same data twice with a type difference, you could store it once with a value which is equal to both.

Comment: @Monofuse enum flags? what is that? Could you show me an example

Comment: An enum is a chunk of bits (think binary 000100010010). Now flags allow you to use each bit (a single 1 or 0) as a value. So lets say you have 3 goal types, kick goal, header goal and home goal. Now kick goal would equal to 1, header goal would be equal to 2 and finally home goal would be equal to 4. Notice the skip there. That's because 1 = 00000001, 2 = 00000010, 00000011 and 4 = 00000100. As stated at first each value owns a bit, as 3 is made up as two bits you can't use it as a distinct value. 3 - 00000011 actual would mean the goal was a kick goal and header goal.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx

Comment: When I get a minute I'll write up a none language specific tutorial for you.

Comment: If a goal was a header goal and a home goal the value would be 6, which would look like this: 00000110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your query.  Why do you have `left join`s?

From my interpretation of your data, you only want to look at goals with `type = 1`.  So, does this do what you want?

```
SELECT p.first_name AS first_name,
       p.last_name AS last_name,
       COUNT(*) AS goal_scored
FROM player p JOIN
     goal g
     ON g.player_marker_id = p.id JOIN
     `match` m
     ON g.match_id = m.id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id AND
      :team_id IN (m.home_team_id, m.away_team_id) AND
      g.type IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY p.first_name, p.last_name
ORDER BY goal_scored DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

You would use `LEFT JOIN` only if you want player that scored no goals.

Comment: Please check my update, the result displayed in the image is the correct goal scored by the player: 9 goals. The problem is the type, infact I have also duplicate rows that's why the total is incorrect, I don't understand how can I manage this. Your query return 4, but the correct result for Benedetto is 9

Comment: because @jidic limit type to 1. Change it to g.type in (1,2) and you got what you want

Comment: @Livius I changed it to:  g.type = 1 OR g.type = 2 and I get completely wrong result, now I got a player scored goals 74, that's impossible

Comment: Do you have parentchesis around this OR? Why not "in (1,2) "?

Comment: @Livius didn't saw the edit of gordon answer, this work's many thanks I was stucked by hours on this